# is there an uninstall equivalent to "pip install --user <package>"?

Tags: python, pip

Our sysadmin has installed a package, so I can remove my local copy. I'd like to say

```
pip uninstall --user <package>
```

but `pip uninstall` does not support `--user`. (At least `pip 1.5.4` on Linux doesn't.)
Is there an easy way to do this by hand, i.e., delete the directory that contains the package?

Comment: First, you should **really** upgrade pip - `pip install -U pip --user`.

Comment: Nope, but you can probably get what you want with virtualenv. By default (in newer versions) it will not inherit anything installed systemwide, so you can install things you need in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a known bug in pip

Ref : https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2094

> As pip uninstall does not have --user option unlike pip install the question is if there even exists a way to uninstall package installed with pip install --user?

It is now cleared with a note

> The packages mentioned in the ticket started working after they offered Wheel-based packages.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that upgrading the package first will let you uninstall the package that you installed with *--user* option. For my case was elevated:

I have installed with command:

```
pip3 install --user elevate
```

When i try to uninstall i recieve the skip info:

```
Skipping elevate as it is not installed.
```

After many unsuccessfull commands i have found that i need to update the package first with:

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade elevated
```

Then i was able to successfully uninstall the elevate package:

```
pip3 uninstall elevated
```